How do I use Flutter's hot reload for a web app that uses Firebase?
I am building a web app using Flutter and Firebase. If I make a change and save it, Chrome will perform a hot restart (opposed to a hot reload). I could build it to Windows instead, so I could take advantage of the hot reload, but Firebase is not supported on Windows apps.
How can I use both Firebase and Hot Reload for my Flutter web app?

Flutter for Web does not support hot reload.
From the Flutter documentation on building for web:

Hot reload is not supported in a web browser. Currently, Flutter only supports hot restart, which restarts your app without refreshing the web page.

So regardless of Firebase, Flutter doesn't support hot-reload for web apps.
